# Does Mathematica 13.1 work well with the MacBook Air M2 2022 Screen Bezel?

Tags: compatibility, hardware

There are reports stating that some applications do not work well with the screen bezel in MacBook Air 2022 which hides some menus.

I see in the previous MacBook Air M1 that a couple of menus in Mathematica 13.1 are at the same location than the camera, so I presume the bezel will be at the same location.

Can anyone share if Mathematica 13.1 works well on a MacBook Air M2 2022 model (specifically with the Screen Bezel, but also on the M2 chip itself)?